# Which patterns used to select the element?

Tags: css

I learn css3 selectors, and i can't understand what is the difference between the following selectors:

```
div > div 
div + div
div ~ div
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please check the documentation first, it is well explained there (check under **Combinators**): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**element>element**
for example : `div > p`
Selects all

elements where the parent is a  element

**element+element**
for example :`div + p`
Selects all

elements that are placed immediately after  elements

**element1~element2**
for example : `p ~ ul`
Selects every  element that are preceded by a

element

see this like for all css selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: tnx that war perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

`div > p` Selects all p elements where the parent is a div element

`div + p` Selects all p elements that are placed immediately after div elements

`p ~ ul` Selects every ul element that are preceded by a p element

Here's a complete reference to all selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

A simple example

```css
div > p{
color:blue;
}

div+p{
color:green;
}

#para ~ p{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Hello, im a child of div</p>
</div>

<p id="para">Hello, im adjacent to a div</p>

<p>Hello, im preceding to a div</p>
```

Comment: tnx that war perfect :)